# Why is decryption failing after separate writes to this file-like object?

Tags: python, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, pycrypto

I'm working on a toy module to encrypt tempfiles.  The idea is to expose an interface similar to that found in the `tempfile` module, but to have data transparently encrypted using session keys.  Again, it's just a toy project and not production code.

First, a few technical details.  This project is implemented with `pycrypto` and is employing:

- AES-CTR
- A counter with a 1-bit randomized prefix

The basic class is structured so as to mimic the file object interface.  When a method such as `read` or `write` is called, we initialize a `Crypto.Cipher.AES` object using the class' `_cipher` property.  This property is implemented as follows:

```
def _cipher():
    doc = doc = "Returns a stateful AES object ready to decrypt at the required \
                 stream position"

    def fget(self):
        ctr = Counter.new(nbits=64,
                          initial_value=self.tell()  # alias of self._file.tell
                          prefix=self._nonce)  # set by `Random.new().read(8)
        return AES.new(self._key, counter=ctr, mode=self._opmode)  # self._opmode = Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR

    def fset(self, value):
        raise AttributeError('Cannot set _cipher')

    def fdel(self, value):
        raise AttributeError('Cannot delete _cipher')

    return locals()
        _cipher = property(**_cipher())
```

Here is an example of how the `_cipher` property is used to encrypt transparently during a call to the `write` method.

```
def write(self, data):
    if not isinstance(data, str):
        raise TypeError('Data must be str (or bytestring)')
    self._file.write(self._cipher.encrypt(data))
```

When decrypting, we apply the opposite transaction as such:

```
def read(self, size=-1):
    return self._cipher.decrypt(self._file.read(size))
```

This works when making single calls to `write`, but fails when multiple calls to `write` are chained.  For instance:

```
ep = EphemeralFile()  # the class in question
ep.write('Now is the winter of our discontent')
ep.seek(0)
print ep.read()

>> Now is the winter of our discontent
```

So far so good... but here's where it fails

```
ep.write(' made glorious summer by this sun of York')
ep.seek(0)
print ep.read()

>> Now is the winter of our discontent"d_"��U�L~ �w���S��h��]"U(��P^��9k
```

What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't the use of `self._file.tell()` in the `_cipher` property yield the appropriate counter position for decryption?

Please note that I first suspected that I might be off by one counter tick, so I tried modifying the `initial_value=self.tell()` line to `initial_value=self.tell() + 1` (also tried with `-1`), but to no avail.

For convenience, here is the full class definition.  It's fairly short and may yield some insight.

```
import tempfile

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Util import Counter

PRNG = Random.new()


class EphemeralFile(object):
    def __init__(self, mode='w+b', bufsize=-1, suffix='', prefix='', dir=None,
                 key_size=32):

        self._key = PRNG.read(key_size)
        self._nonce = PRNG.read(8)
        self._opmode = AES.MODE_CTR

        self._file = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode=mode, bufsize=bufsize,
                                            suffix=suffix, prefix=prefix, dir=dir)

        # alias tempfile methods and parameters
        self.close = self._file.close
        self.closed = self._file.closed
        self.encoding = self._file.encoding
        self.errors = self._file.errors
        self.fileno = self._file.fileno
        self.flush = self._file.flush
        self.isatty = self._file.isatty
        self.mode = self._file.mode
        self.name = self._file.name
        self.softspace = self._file.softspace
        self.truncate = self._file.truncate
        self.seek = self._file.seek
        self.tell = self._file.tell

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._file.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return (line for line in self.readlines())

    def _cipher():
        doc = "Returns a stateful AES object ready to decrypt at the required \
               stream position"

        def fget(self):
            ctr = Counter.new(nbits=64,
                              initial_value=self.tell(),
                              prefix=self._nonce)
            return AES.new(self._key, counter=ctr, mode=self._opmode)

        def fset(self, value):
            raise AttributeError('Cannot set EphemeralFile._cipher')

        def fdel(self):
            raise AttributeError('Cannot delete EphemeralFile._cipher')

        return locals()
    _cipher = property(**_cipher())

    def write(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, str):
            raise TypeError('Data must be str (or bytestring)')

        self._file.write(self._cipher.encrypt(data))

    def writelines(self, lines):
        self.write("\n".join(lines))

    def read(self, size=-1):
        return self._cipher.decrypt(self._file.read(size))

    def readline(self, size=-1):
        fptr = self.tell()
        bytes = []
        got_line = False
        while not got_line:
            bytes.append(self.read(1))
            if not bytes[-1] or ('\n' in bytes[-1]):
                bytes[-1] = bytes[-1][0:bytes[-1].find('\n') + 1]
                got_line = True

        plaintext = ''.join(bytes)
        self.seek(fptr + len(plaintext))  # rewind
        return plaintext

    def readlines(self, size=-1):
        return [line for line in self]

    def read_ciphertext(self, size=-1):
        """Read ciphertext without decrypting.

        size : int (default -1)
            Number of bytes to read.  Negative values read the entire stream

        return : str
            Ciphertext
        """
        return self._file.read(size)

    def next(self):
        return self.readline()
```

At this point I really don't see where the problem is, so please feel free to nag me with questions and suggest possible solutions.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe one problem is that the `Counter` object should receive as `initial_value` the AES block number, not the byte offset. In other words, you need to have:

```
ctr = Counter.new(nbits=64,
                  initial_value=self.tell() % 16,
                  prefix=self._nonce)
```

That's needed because in AES CTR mode you increase the value each time you cross the AES data boundary (16 bytes).

That also means that the correct sequence for any `write` operation roughly is:

1. Start the cipher object as shown above - in encryption mode.
2. Encrypt `self.tell() % 16` bytes of any data and throw away the result.
3. Encrypt the input data and write it to the file.

Similarly for reading:

1. Start the cipher object as shown above - in decryption mode.
2. Decrypt `self.tell() % 16` bytes of any data and throw away the result.
3. Decrypt the data read from the file.

<strike>From a quick look at the code, a second problem could also be that you use the same AES object for both encryption and decryption. You need two separate objects, one for each direction.</strike>

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your insightful answer!  I'm still not clear on why I need to perform step 2 in both encryption and decryption -- doesn't the `initial_value` kwarg offset the counter?

Comment: Also, I didn't get the impression that `AES` objects had encryption-specific or decryption-specific modes.  My understanding was that encryption vs. decryption was determined based on the method being called (i.e., `AES.encrypt` vs. `AES.decrypt`).  And besides, the property makes it so that a seperate `AES` object is obtained with each call to `_cipher`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @blz It helps to look at the [wikipedia diagram for CTR mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29). Encryption is done by XOR-ing the input data with a sequence of 16 bytes blocks, called key stream. If you start encryption mid-block (as it may happen with most calls to `write()` other than the first) you must "fast-forward" a few bytes to reach the correct piece of the key stream. The `initial_value` selects the block number, not the offset within the block.

Comment: @blz I had a closer look at the code and indeed the second problem I mention is bogus. You indeed instantiate a block for every operation.